# Python json.dumps() outputs all my data into one line but I want to have a new line for each entry

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

I am working with Python and some json data. I am looping through my data (which are all dictionaries) and when I print the loop values to my console, I get 1 dictionary per line.

However, when I do the same line of code with json.dumps() to convert my object into a string to be able to be output, I get multiple lines within the dictionary versus wanting the new line outside the dictionary.

How do you add new lines after each dictionary value when looping?

Code example:

```
    def test(values, filename):
      with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for value in values:
            print(json.dumps(value, sort_keys=True)) # gives me each dictionary in a new line
            f.write(json.dumps(value, sort_keys=True, indent=0) #gives me a new line for each key/value pair instead of after each dictionary.
```

Output in the console:

```
{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith", "food": "corn"}
{"first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Doe", "food": "soup"}
```

Output in my output file:

```
{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith", "food": "corn"}{"first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Doe", "food": "soup"}
```

What code am I missing to get a new line for each dictionary value so that my output file looks the same as my console?

Comment: Note that if you dump and write one value at a time you will not produce valid json file, but [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/) file. i.e. your file will not be valid json, but each line in itself will be valid json. Is this really what you want?

Comment: `print` adds a line break. `file.write` doesn't.

Comment: You could do `print(json.dumps(value, sort_keys=True), file=f)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can newline after each

```
f.write(json.dumps(value, sort_keys=True, indent=0))
```

like this - `f.write('\n')`

Comment: Thank you. My output file looks exactly how I wanted it! :)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to produce valid JSON file you need to write all values at once, not one value at a time (which will produce [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/) or [JSON lines](https://jsonlines.org/))

So, for a valid JSON

```
values = [{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith", "food": "corn"},
          {"first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Doe", "food": "soup"}]

import json
with open('some_file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(values, f, indent=4)
```

**some_file.json**

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "food": "corn"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "food": "soup"
    }
]
```

if you really need `ndjson` - you can use [ndjson package](https://pypi.org/project/ndjson/) (need install via `pip` from PyPi).

```
import ndjson

with open('some_file2.ndjson', 'w') as f:
    ndjson.dump(values, f)
```

**some_file2.ndjson**

```
{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith", "food": "corn"}
{"first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Doe", "food": "soup"}
```

Alternative to `ndjson` package is [jsonlines](https://pypi.org/project/jsonlines/) package

Answer (score 3):

You just have to append a newline character after every iteration.

`f.write("\n")`

Also please don't be confused with `writelines` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines). It doesn't append newline character either, so you have to take care of it yourself anyway.